# How to create editable nested tree view in odoo 10

Tags: python-2.7, treeview, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I have a following model:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api


class OrgEntry(models.Model):
    _name = 'org.entry'

    name = fields.Char('Name')
    parent_id = fields.Many2one('org.entry', 'Parent')
    child_ids = fields.One2many('org.entry', 'parent_id', 'Child')
    is_job = fields.Boolean('Some')
```

Each org entry can be parent / child to itself. What I need to do is to create editable (I can add / remove/ edit org_entries) nested (If format: Parent -> Child -> Child etc) treeview.

My view.xml so far looks like this:

```
    <record id="action_org_entry_grouped" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Departments</field>
        <field name="res_model">org.entry</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="domain">[('parent_id','=',False)]</field>
        <field name="context">{'group_by':['parent_id']}</field>
    </record>

    <record id="view_org_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">org.entry.select</field>
        <field name="model">org.entry</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Search Org">
                <filter string="Parent" context="{'group_by':'parent_id'}"/>
            </search>
        </field>
    </record>


    <act_window id="action_org_entry_tree"
        name="Org Entry"
        res_model="org.entry"
        view_mode="tree" />

    <menuitem
      id="menu_hr_department_test"
      name="Організаційна структура"
      action="action_org_entry_tree"
      parent="hr.menu_hr_root"
      sequence="97"
      groups="hr.group_hr_manager"/>

</data>
```

If in menuitem action I set `action_org_entry_grouped` I get "kind" of grouped entries - I see only parents without arrow to unfold. In this case there is also no buttons to create / import.

If `action_org_entry_tree` is set as action - I just see list of all existing entries without any grouping at all but with create / import buttons.

I've checked a lot of answers for similar questions but with no luck in applying it to my problem.

Comment: go to module account under folder report you will find an example how to do that you need to specify children_ids in the tree view also the tree cannot be editable when you click on item i won't do nothing.

Comment: Could you, please, be more specific. What file should I check `account_invoice_report_view`? What record does something similar to what I'm trying to achieve?